# ajax url not found "NetworkError: 404 Not Found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, url

I have two jsp pages. `newEmployee.jsp` and `editData.jsp`, both have a srcipt linked to myjScript.js. Once the user submits the state and country information in `newEmployee.jsp` it comes to `editData.jsp`.

Now, in script (i.e, on the same page) section of `editData.jsp`, I have a ajax call which should fire to `SelectEditData.java`, but it says not found. (this is the servlet).

```
@WebServlet("/SelectEditData")
public class SelectEditData extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside edit data servlet");

        JsonArray data_json = new JsonArray();

        try {
            Connection con = ConnectionClass.getConnecton();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM selectboxschema.new_table";
            System.out.println("details query " + query);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            JsonObject json_response = new JsonObject();
            while (rs.next()) {

                System.out.println("result set: " + rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println("result set: " + rs.getString(2));

                JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                json.addProperty("firstData", rs.getString(1));
                json.addProperty("secondData", rs.getString(2));

                data_json.add(json);
            }


            json_response.add("aData", data_json);
            System.out.println("json response: " + json_response.toString());
            response.setContentType("application/Json");

            response.getWriter().write(json_response.toString());



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception caught in edit data servlet" + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

}
```

```js
//this is jScript.js

function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

 var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

 var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

 stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
 stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
 stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

 var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

 for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
  stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],
    state_arr[i]);
 }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
 // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts
 // <option> tags
 var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
 countryElement.length = 0;
 countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
 countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
  countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(
    country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
 }

 // Assigned all countries. Event listener for the states.

 if (stateElementId) {
  countryElement.onchange = function() {
   populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
  };
 }
}
```

```html
//this is the editData.jsp



<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 alert("ready of edit");
 
 $.ajax({
  
  type : "GET",
  url : "SelectBoxEdit/SelectEditData",
  dataType : "json",

  success : function(data) {
   console.log(data);

   $.each(data.aData, function(i, obj) {
    alert("data: " + obj.firstTable);
    var div_data = "<option selected="
      + "selected" + ">"
      + obj.firstData + "</option>";
    alert(div_data);
    console.log(div_data);
    $(div_data).appendTo('#country');
    
    
   });
  }
 });

</script>




<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
        <hr/>
        <br/>Select Country (with states):
        <select id="country" name="country"></select>
        <br />State:
        <select name="state" id="state"></select>
        <br/>
        
        <script language="javascript">
      populateCountries("country", "state");
        
        </script>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br />
        <br />
       <input type="button" id="submitBtn"> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your ajax url is correct or not

Comment: when I run the above code it gives the following error in firebug 
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/SelectBoxEdit/SelectBoxEdit/SelectEditData"
 when i change it to url: "/SelectEditData" it gives :
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/SelectEditData"

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically get the url and just append "/SelectEditData" to it . I think this should work. But i dont know how to dynamically get the url. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your request URL is correct.

1. use the `/yourServletPath`, this will generate the request URL like http://localhost:8080/yourServletPath. which is without context path.
2. if you should add the context path, and maybe your context path will change later. You can add a `<input type="hidden" id="request_url" value="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/yourServletPath"/>` and then when you do the ajax request, you can use get it in your javascript code like: `$('#request_url').val()`.

Comment: Don't bother with the hidden form input - the OP can just in-line (before the alert) like this: var ctxPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to $('#request_url').val() in alert , but it showed undefined.

Comment: @DaveG I have tried it and got the url .
url : ctxPath+"/SelectEditData",
 But still the servlet is not hit. I got this error: 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/SelectBoxEdit/SelectEditData
I am using anotation to map the servlet and not mapped it in web.xml. Is that the issue by any reason?

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee what is your container (tomcat?) and is your web.xml setup as a webapp 3.0 or greater configuration? Can you manually request that URL you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks to all. It is working now. Its when @DaveG pointed to manually request that URL, I tried and its not working. So I started the server from startup.bat and deployed the war file. The servlet got hit. Thanks for also teaching me how to get the url.